# Pivot Dynamic columns Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a table that looks something like this

```
StudentNr    Module    MarkAchieved
123          Task1     59
123          Task2     49
123          Exam1     62
854          Task1     71
854          Task2     72
854          Exam1     90
785          Task1     41
785          Task2     53
785          Exam1     60
```

That I want to be displayed like This

```
StudentNr    Task1     Task2     Exam1
123          59        49        62
854          71        72        90
785          41        53        60
```

**My problem is I don't know how many Modules there will be**

I know how to and have gotten the pivot to work but not with Dynamic columns.
How can I Pivot my table with **Dynamic** columns ?

Comment: Have you ever looked at the [PIVOT syntax](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)?

Comment: Yes I've Tried http://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/ And I can get the pivot to work but not Dynamically

Comment: That article, if you read it, uses objects that are not part of standard SQL...

Comment: Ah I see thanks Ben, I hope it's possible to pivot with Dynamic columns in Oracle...

Comment: It is... I've closed this as a duplicate of something that tells you how. It is _really_ worth reading the docs though.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what your query should look like:

```
select *
from
(
  select * from t
)
pivot (max(MarkAchieved) for (Module) in ('Task1' as task1, 'Task2' as task2, 'Exam1' as exam1))
;
```

This gives:

```
STUDENTNR   TASK1   TASK2   EXAM1
123         59      49      62
785         41      53      60
854         71      72      90
```

Now, the problem with the `PIVOT` clause in Oracle 11g is that you have to enumerate explicitly all the possible values... This is a limitation, that the `PIVOT XML` clause does not have for instance (but it will generate XML... yeah, life is bad sometimes).

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel, but my issue is still That I don't know what modules there will be so I can't hardcode the modules